# How to call Low-Level KeyHook Key-Combinations?

Tags: c#

I really can't solve this problem and don't even know, if it is possible.

I want to use **CTRL+C** and **CTRL+V** shortcuts.

Example: There is 2 Application. 1. App is written in C#, 2. App is an Java-Applet.
I want to Copy string from C# App. and paste it into *focused Textbox* in Java-Applet.

I ll copy the string in to Clipboard and I need to Paste it into the focused Textbox in Java-Applet.

```
string data = "12345";
Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, (Object)data);
```

Now I need to paste this information into the Textbox in Applet.

How can I Call CTRL+V shortcuts in C#?

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be to use [InputSimulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) which is a very flexible (and reliable) wrapper that is capable of simulating keyboard and mouse events.

It wraps SendInput under the hood but abstracts away all the PInvoke calls and other complexity.  It's a drop in DLL that (for your situation) should only take a couple lines of code.

```
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyDown(VirtualKeyCode.CTRL);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.KEYS_V);
InputSimulator.SimulateKeyUp(VirtualKeyCode.CTRL);
```

or

```
InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
```

Comment: The docs list the syntax for CTRL-C as InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);

Comment: Thanks @StuartDunkeld, I'll update the answer to reflect the shorter command.

Answer (score 2):

See [How to: Simulate Mouse and Keyboard Events in Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) for examples of using [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) to send keystrokes to a different application.